# The order of variables in ANOVA matters, doesn't it?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, anova, unbalanced-classes, sums-of-squares

Am I correct to understand that the order in which variables are specified in a multifactorial ANOVA makes a difference but that the order does not matter when doing a multiple linear regression?

So assuming an outcome such as *measured blood loss* `y` and two categorical variables

1. *adenoidectomy method* `a`,
2. *tonsillectomy method* `b`.

The model `y~a+b` is different to the model `y~b+a` (or so my implementation in R seems to indicate).

Am I correct to understand that the term here is that ANOVA is a **hierarchical** model since it first attributes as much variance as it can to the first factor before trying to attribute residual variance to the second factor?

In the example above the hierarchy makes sense because I always do the adenoidectomy first before doing the tonsillectomy but what would happen if one had two variables with no inherent order?

Comment: Order matters in ANOVAs with unbalanced designs, i.e., when there are unequal cell sizes. This topic is often treated under the headline of "types of sums of squares". See http://epm.sagepub.com/content/38/3/621.full.pdf+html and chl's answer to http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11209/the-effect-of-the-number-of-replicates-in-different-cells-on-the-results-of-anova

Comment: See also gung's answer in http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20452.

Comment: I've just extended an older discussion of mine hoping it shall shed another light on the matter. It surely still needs work, and possibly someone has the nerves to help editing it. Here is what I have so far: http://go.helms-net.de/stat/div/%28SSE%29%20ANovaRegression_SPSS_R.htm Possibly there is something interesting with the potential to be extracted to some explicite answer to that question here.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This question evidently came from a study with an unbalanced two-way design, analyzed in R with the `aov()` function; [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/212496/28500) provides a more recent and detailed example of this issue.

The general answer to this question, as to so many, is: "It depends." Here it depends on whether the design is balanced and, if not, which flavor of ANOVA is chosen.

First, it depends on whether the design is balanced. In the best of all possible worlds, with equal numbers of cases in all cells of a factorial design, there would be no difference due to the order of entering the factors into the model, regardless of how ANOVA is performed.* The cases at hand, evidently from a retrospective clinical cohort, seem to be from a real world where such balance was not found. So the order *might* matter.

Second, it depends on how the ANOVA is performed, which is a somewhat contentious issue. The types of ANOVA for unbalanced designs differ in the order of evaluating main effects and interactions. Evaluating interactions is fundamental to two-way and higher-order ANOVA, so there are disputes over the best way to proceed. See [this Cross Validated page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20452/28500) for one explanation and discussion. See the Details and the Warning for the `Anova()` (with a capital "A") function in the [manual for the `car` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/car/car.pdf) for a different view.

The order of factors *does* matter in unbalanced designs under the default `aov()` in R, which uses what are called type-I tests. These are sequential attributions of variance to factors in the order of entry into the model, as the present question envisioned. The order *does not* matter with the type-II or type-III tests provided by the `Anova()` function in the `car` package in R. These alternatives, however, have their own potential disadvantages noted in the above links.

Finally, consider the relation to multiple linear regression as with `lm()` in R, which is essentially the same type of model if you include interaction terms. The order of entry of variables in `lm()` does not matter in terms of regression coefficients and *p*-values reported by `summary(lm())`, in which a k-level categorical factor is coded as (k-1) binary dummy variables and a regression coefficient is reported for each dummy.

It is, however, possible to wrap the `lm()` output with `anova()` (lower-case "a," from the R `stats` package) or `Anova()` to summarize the influence of each factor over all of its levels, as one expects in classical ANOVA. Then the ordering of factors will matter with `anova()` as for `aov()`, and will not matter with `Anova()`. Similarly, the disputes over which type of ANOVA to use would return. So it's not safe to assume order-independence of factor entry with all downstream uses of `lm()` models.

---

*Having equal numbers of observations in all cells is sufficient but, as I understand it, not necessary for the order of factors to be irrelevant. Less demanding types of balance may allow for order-independence.

Comment: Indeed yes, that observational data was unbalanced, very unbalanced.

Comment: Hopefully this comment still gets an answer here: You say that, under a balanced study design, the SS estimate will never be order dependent, irregardless of the type of anova test (typeI, II, III) chosen. I am not sure if I understand this. using the 'anova' function in R (which uses type I tests) on a linear model based on data that is balanced, surely the feature order matters, no?

Comment: @PejoPhylo when the data are balanced then you can have what is called an orthogonal design. With an orthogonal design there is one unique way to partition the sums of squares among the treatments and their interactions, so the order of entry of treatments will not matter with respect to estimates of effects and their p-values. [This page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/85917/28500) provides a mathematical explanation. This is not immediately obvious; the question I just linked was asked by a member of this site with one of the highest reputations. Unbalanced data can destroy orthogonality.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @EdM

Comment: the order matters in `car::Anova` with type-II or -III for the models without Intercept: DV ~ -1 + IV1—IV2—IV3 (where — is + or ×): whatever IV comes first it is significant (with my data). Why?

Comment: @stan I haven't worked through the calculations, but I suspect that comes from the [bias introduced by omitting the intercept](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/7948/28500) and how that plays out in an unbalanced design. You almost certainly should _not_ be omitting an intercept. Search for "regression" "omit" "intercept" on this site.

Comment: @EdM: thank for the reply. I also came to a conclusion that omitting of intercept is a bad idea (at least in my case) — when I included it in the equation I got stable/expected results despite the order of terms. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

The term hierarchical model refers to the structure between the factors. For example, a multi-center study is hierarchical: You have the patients nested within the hospitals treating them. Each hospital treats patients with placebo and verum, but recieving each of them in either hospital A or B is slightly different due to some common effect of the hospital governing on all their patients (might even be an interaction effect with the experimental agent). So it's called hierarchical effect.

Now your ectomy methods may be hierarchical: Is it plausible that a certain tonsillectomy method is slightly different (in itself, not yet in the effect, because that's what your are going to estimate and test) depending on the adenoidectomy method used prior on the same patient? If yes, you should specify it in your model.

Your observation that y~a+b may be different from y~b+a indicates that there is something wrong. Additive effects commute, so there should not be a difference (apart from small numerical differences). It is neither plausible nor desired that the effect of the surgery methods may depend on the order in which the statistician later specifies the effects. So you probably picked the wrong approach to feed `R` with the data.

Comment: I am not sure I follow the last paragraph. In unbalanced factorial ANOVA the p-values for each factor computed via Type I (sequential) sum of squares will certainly dependent on the order of the factors. I believe this is the whole point of the question.

Comment: I'm not sure if @Farrel got Type I SS. I remember I once observed SAS to output different Type III SS due to some disparate sorting in the data set and model statement. Maybe this can happen with R, too?

Comment: Also, I'm not convinced of this Type I SS. Technically these different SS are linked to the choice of a g-inverse to find the estimators, which in turn is linked to estimability. Non-uniqueness is often a hint that you picked the wrong procedure. If there is a difference between surgery methods, this difference is unique. So your estimator should be unique, too.

Comment: I cannot know for a fact and he might not remember himself given that the Q was asked five years ago. But I think this is **by far** the most parsimonious interpretation of his words "The model y~a+b is different to the model y~b+a (or so my implementation in R seems to indicate)", in particular given the fact that `aov` command in R uses Type I SS by default. When I offered the bounty, I expected to get an answer explaining the issues behind unbalanced anova design, differences between Type I/II/III SS, and some comments on whether linear regression does or doesn't have the same issues.

Comment: As linear regression data usually do not result in singular design matrices, we don't have to bother with g-inverses. We already get the unique matrix inverse for the hat-matrix, so the estimators will be unique, too. Is this some approach to the kind of answer you expected? However, in the rare case of singular design matrices with regression data, the wrong choice of SS might actually be an issue.

Comment: No. Design matrix is singular in anova even if it is balanced, when there is no difference between SS I/II/III. The SS I/II/III are different only in the unbalanced case because the factors become non-orthogonal (unlike in the balanced case). In my understanding, this corresponds to a linear regression with correlated predictors, which is a very common situation. My answer is that the same issue occurs in regression too, it's just that it is standard to compute a p-value of one predictor after accounting for the effects of all other predictors; this corresponds to Type III SS in anova.

Comment: OK, you won your own bounty. But I think correlated predictors do not necessarily lead to singular $X'X$ with $X$ in $Y=Xb+\epsilon$. They have to be linearly dependend as the predictors (then dummy variables) are in every overparametrized Anova model.

Comment: In this case I did not offer the bounty to learn something, I offered it to avoid writing an answer myself...

Comment: @amoeba: for your second comment: please see my comment at the original question; I've made -primarily for my selfstudy- a "worksheet" for an illustration of the whereabouts of the SS-type differences and whether they are relevant for regression. I understand it as still under construction and am thankful for comments and corrections.

Comment: Such questions about variable order in ANOVA keep coming in, like [this one](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/212496/28500) migrated from Stack Overflow yesterday. I think it's safe to assume that this 5-year-old question was similarly based on `aov` rather than `lm`, and it would be helpful to have an answer to this question of the type that @amoeba indicated in the comment from May 12, 14:31.

Comment: @EdM, Indeed, and I encourage you to post such an answer! +1 to your new answer in the linked thread, by the way.

Comment: @amoeba, I know enough to know what I don't know enough about. I get much too confused by unbalanced designs, I have insufficient theoretical background to provide a compelling general answer of the type that the question deserves, and not enough time right now to do the research to provide one. I'm basically limited to the simple guidance I could provide to a struggling fellow biologist in the linked thread. Hope one of the more technically competent folks conversing here can get a good answer together.