# Is glm(A~B*C*D) the same as glm(A~C*B*D)?

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model

When I run these two in R, I get different values. I thought that I should get the same values since it just includes their interaction terms.

Comment: Did you check whether you got the same predictions?

Comment: they are the same. I am more interested in analyzing each coefficient to see how well they fit the model. I don't understand why B * C * D is different than C * B * D for the interaction terms, I assumed order doesn't matter

Comment: I'd suggest checking which main effects made it into each model.

Comment: the main effects all have very similar p-values and slopes. I am interested in the interaction terms. Which have changed drastically.

Comment: Not only the slopes have changed, but what the interaction terms represent have also changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The order of variables in ANOVA matters, doesn't it?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13241/the-order-of-variables-in-anova-matters-doesnt-it)