# Order of Independent variables in regression

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, p-value

I've data `df` and i'm wondering why p-value change according the order of the independent variables `product` and `age` ?

How to know which one to place firstly ?

```
     df=structure(list(Age = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
        4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
        4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
        5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
        6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
        7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
        7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
        8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 
        9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
        9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
        10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 
        11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 13L, NA), .Label = c("(10,15]", 
        "(15,20]", "(20,25]", "(25,30]", "(30,35]", "(35,40]", "(40,45]", 
        "(45,50]", "(50,55]", "(55,60]", "(60,65]", "(65,70]", "(70,75]", 
        "(75,80]"), class = "factor"), Product = c(6L, 16L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 
        11L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 20L, 23L, 26L, 28L, 30L, 32L, 33L, 36L, 44L, 
        47L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 11L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 20L, 23L, 25L, 26L, 
        28L, 30L, 32L, 33L, 36L, 44L, 50L, 51L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 11L, 14L, 
        15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 20L, 22L, 23L, 26L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 32L, 33L, 
        36L, 37L, 39L, 43L, 44L, 50L, 51L, 58L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 11L, 14L, 
        15L, 17L, 18L, 20L, 23L, 26L, 28L, 30L, 32L, 33L, 36L, 37L, 47L, 
        58L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 11L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 20L, 23L, 25L, 26L, 
        28L, 30L, 33L, 35L, 36L, 44L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 20L, 
        22L, 23L, 25L, 26L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 33L, 36L, 38L, 43L, 44L, 50L, 
        51L, 58L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 11L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 20L, 23L, 25L, 
        26L, 28L, 30L, 32L, 33L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 43L, 44L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 
        58L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 11L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 20L, 23L, 26L, 
        28L, 29L, 30L, 32L, 33L, 36L, 43L, 44L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 4L, 6L, 
        9L, 14L, 17L, 18L, 20L, 23L, 25L, 26L, 28L, 30L, 32L, 33L, 35L, 
        36L, 43L, 44L, 51L, 52L, 58L, 6L, 9L, 20L, 23L, 26L, 28L, 36L, 
        4L, 15L, 6L), Yes = c(2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 
        1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 
        2L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 13L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 
        2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 5L, 
        1L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 
        2L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
        1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
        6L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 
        6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
        3L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
        2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L), No = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
        1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
        0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
        0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
        0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
        0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
        0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
        0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
        0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
        0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
        0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
        0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
        0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
        -203L), .Names = c("Age", "Product", "Yes", "No"))

        attach(df)

       anova(glm(cbind(Yes,No) ~ Age + Product, family=binomial),test="Chisq")
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model: binomial, link: logit

Response: cbind(Yes, No)

Terms added sequentially (first to last)


        Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev Pr(>Chi)  
NULL                      201     176.98           
Age     12  24.4260       189     152.56  0.01779 *
Product  1   1.8942       188     150.66  0.16873  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>         anova(glm(cbind(Yes,No) ~ Product + Age, family=binomial),test="Chisq")
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model: binomial, link: logit

Response: cbind(Yes, No)

Terms added sequentially (first to last)


        Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev Pr(>Chi)  
NULL                      201     176.98           
Product  1   2.9839       200     174.00   0.0841 .
Age     12  23.3364       188     150.66   0.0250 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: This issue is covered in several other places on this site, including [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/13241/28500). Please look at that page and the links from it, and revise your question to focus on what you still don't understand thereafter. Otherwise this is likely to be closed as a duplicate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hypothesis tests that are being performed by the call to anova() are based on adding terms to your model sequentially and asking whether or not each added term improves the model given all of those that came before it.  Hence, a different variable order will result in different hypothesis tests being performed.

For the first table, you begin will the *Null* model--i.e. the model without any independent variables--which has a residual deviance of 176.98.  Upon adding the variable *Age* to your model, the residual deviance drops to 152.56 and a chi-squared test gives a p-value of 0.01779.  That is, the addition of the variable *Age* has arguably improved the fit when compared to the *Null* model.  The third line in the table now says **given** that *Age* is already in the model, what improvement is gained by additionally adding *Product* to the model?  In that case, the drop in the deviance was not large enough to yield a significant p-value.

For the second table, we proceed similarly by beginning with the *Null* model.  The first variable added in this case is *Product*.  Hence, the first p-value of 0.0841 comes from comparing the *Null* model to the model with the independent variable *Product*.  The third line in the table then asks, does the addition of the variable *Age* **given** that we already have the variable *Product* in the model improve the fit?  In this case, one might argue that 0.025 is small enough to declare that adding *Age* does, in fact, improve the model.

Comment: Thank so much for, this,I was stack on it. I understand better. For research purpose, Should I place firstly the variable that is more susceptible to be more implicated and more have impact on the model ? or  is it "ethic" to taket he combination that enhance the p-value of each variables, sometimes significance appears just by reversing the order.

Comment: There's more than one way to proceed.  You could, in general, compare all four possible models--i.e. Null, only Age, only Product, both Age and Product--with some model selection criterion like AIC or BIC to determine the "best".  Given specifically the two tables above, I would conclude that Age is a good predictor whereas Product is not.  Mainly, because the p-value for Product alone is only 0.0841, which doesn't seem very significant.  Of course, many other behaviours are possible especially when a large number of regressors are included in the model.

Comment: The dependence on the order of variables comes from the choice of Type I ANOVA implicit in the `anova()` function in R. There are other Types of ANOVA, as explained for example on [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20452/28500), for which the order of variables in the model does not matter. Those alternatives, however, have other potential downsides. So it's not always an easy choice. Whatever choice about type of ANOVA is made, it's crucial to explain in your writing why the choice was made.