# The Sums of squares in 3 way Anova in R output has changed as the order of the variables in the modes changes

Tags: r, anova, sums-of-squares

I am trying to fit a 3 way ANOVA using R. Then i realized the sums of squares of the output has changed when the order of the variables in the model are changed.[image: R Output]Can anyone figure out the reason for that ? 
There seems to be something wrong because in normal situation the sums of squares in R not affected by the order of variables in the model

Comment: See [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/13241/28500).

Comment: Different "type" sums of squares--see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20452/how-to-interpret-type-i-type-ii-and-type-iii-anova-and-manova

Comment: replace `aov` with `lm` and the order will not matter