# glmmTMB results in R summary() or Anova()?

Tags: r, descriptive-statistics, biostatistics, glmm, glmmtmb

I am wondering how to analyze differences between subspecies. I want to see if body mass differs between 3 subspecies of rodent and if sex and reproductive status are also different. We then want to see if body mass changes between season or is affected by group size.

We decided to use a GLMM model (using the `glmmTMB` package in R) since  multiple body mass values were taken from the same individuals. We added Individual Identity (`AnimalID` in the dataset) as the random variable. Body mass was normally distributed in 2 of the subspecies but not the 3rd. Can we still do a Gaussian distribution? The sample size for the non-normal distribution is 427. The other two have about 100 body mass values.

Our predictors are: subspecies (factor with 3 levels: spp 1, 2, 3), sex (factor 2 levels: M/F), reproductive status (factor 2 levels: Repro/Non-repro), time of year (season: wet/dry), and group size (continuous variable). We will then repeat the models independently for each subspecies.

Our models using R:

```
allspecies <- glmmTMB(Mass ~ Species + Sex + Status + Species*Sex + 
                    Species*Status +
                    Sex*Status + Species*Sex*Status + 
                    (1|AnimalID),family=gaussian() , data = adults) 

species1 <- glmmTMB(Mass ~ Sex + Status + Sex*Status + GroupSize + 
                    Season + GroupSize*Season + 
                    (1|AnimalID),family=gaussian() , data = species1) 
#this last model then is run using the other 2 species datasets
```

When I want to get summary statistics to check which predictors affect body mass, do I run `summary(mod)` or `car::Anova(mod)` in R? We are having a disagreement on which to do.

Comment: Is there some reason why you are doing separate models for each of the sub-species? The most efficient use of data is generally to use a single model within which you can estimate both within-sub-species and between-sub-species differences. The distribution of body mass per se doesn't have to be normal; ideally you would want the residuals around predicted values to be normal but even that isn't strictly necessary. It's important to get the model form correct; there are many ways to get summaries of the model results thereafter.

Comment: Sorrry, when I said not normal, I meant the residuals were not normally distributed for the one subspecies. We thought that adding GroupSize and Season to the main model would confuse things and require post hoc tests to tell in which subspecies a significant effect was occuring. So we want to remove confusion for us and do a single model for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you include interactions in your model, no single `summary()` function is likely to tell you "which predictors affect body mass." Results reported by `summary()` typically just display whether a coefficient estimate is significantly different from a value of 0. For a predictor involved in interactions, its individual coefficient will typically be the value when all of its interacting predictors are at 0 or reference levels (for continuous resp. categorical predictors). Thus the reported individual coefficient for one predictor might differ or not from 0 depending on how its *interacting* predictors are coded! See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/417159/28500) for further explanation.

In a perfectly balanced design, `Anova()` might do what you wish with respect to "statistical significance." Otherwise, you have to consider the different [types of ANOVA](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/213358/28500) and which one best meets your needs. If residuals are far from normally distributed, you might not be meeting the technical requirements of those tests although the large number of cases might make that less crucial here. Furthermore, ANOVA by itself doesn't tell you the magnitudes of the associated differences. With a large study you might have a "statistically significant" difference that is of little practical importance

With interactions, most interesting results (except for the "statistical significance" of the highest-level interaction itself) thus *depend on* some type of post-hoc test* to evaluate particular combinations of predictors of interest. Wald tests on all coefficients involving a predictor (its own, its nonlinear terms, and its interactions) together can evaluate the statistical significance of that predictor. For magnitudes of effects you can evaluate differences between different scenarios, for example via the [`emmeans` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans).

Thus I'd recommend going back to a single model and plan on performing critical specific tests to evaluate *how much* your "predictors affect body mass."

---

*My use of "post-hoc test" here maybe isn't quite correct. That term sometimes is restricted to a test that wasn't pre-planned. I'm using it in the way implied by a comment, as a test on coefficients that isn't directly reported by a `summary` or `ANOVA` function.

Comment: Thanks EdM for your helpful response. I think we tried emmeans but had some confusing results. We will have another look.

Comment: @KyleFinn there can be something of a learning curve to get started with some broadly useful packages like `emmeans` and `rms`, but it's worth it. A quick look at the documentation suggests there might be some issues specific to `glmmTMB`; the package author can be quite responsive. The `emmeans` package forces you to be quite careful with interactions, which is a good thing. For interpretation of `emmeans`, add the `lsmeans` tag to a new question here.