# Why do anova(lm( )) and summary(lm( )) yield different p-values for a factor with two levels?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, anova, generalized-linear-model, lsmeans

Why do `anova(lm( ))` and `summary(lm( ))` (in R) yield different p-values for a factor `f` with two levels?

The model is `y ~ f + c`, `f` has two levels (unequal sample size) and `c` is numeric.

````r
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(
  y = rnorm(1000),
  f = sample(c("a","b"), 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(.2,.8)),
  c = rnorm(1000)
)

fit <- lm(y ~ f + c, data = df); 

anova(fit)                 # p = 0.54553
summary(fit)               # p = 0.5191

library(emmeans)
emmeans(fit, pairwise ~ f) # p = 0.5191

# edit: in addition...
library(car)
Anova(fit)                 # p = 0.5191
```
````

Comment: If you use `library(car); Anova(fit)` instead of `anova(fit)`, you'll get the same *p*-value as in the other methods.

Comment: @SalMangiafico But why is that the case?

Comment: Try `fit2 <- lm(y ~ c + f, data = df)`; you'll get the same results for the `f` _p_-value as with `car::Anova()` or `emmeans()` or `summary()`. That for `c` is now different. With unbalanced designs the Type I ANOVA done by `anova()` isn't to be trusted. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/13241/28500).

Comment: Oh my, I thought it defaulted to Type II

Comment: You're clearly not the only one who thought that! Type II tests are default for `car::Anova()`.