# Multiple comparisons with ANOVA including one between and one within-subject effect

Tags: r, anova, multiple-comparisons, lme4-nlme

I'm trying to look at multiple comparisons (across levels of my between subjects factor) for a model with one between-subject factor and one within-subject factor. I was trying to use TukeyHSD on an aovlist object, and then found out that I couldn't do that.

After some browsing, I found how to do what I wanted using `lme()` and `glht()`:

```
options(contrasts=c("contr.sum", "contr.poly"))
lme_model=lme(dv ~ between*within, data frame, random=~1|ID,
              correlation=corCompSymm(form=~1|ID))
anova(lme_model, type="marginal")
summary(glht(lme_model, linfct=mcp(between="Tukey")))
```

It seems to work (the `anova()` results seem to jive with what I was getting from `aov()`), but I guess the problem is that I don't really understand what `lme()` is, or what it's doing. Does anyone have any documentation that I can look at?

Answer (score 4):

The `lme()` function, from the [nlme](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nlme/index.html) package (or see the [companion website](http://stat.bell-labs.com/project/nlme/)), allows to fit mixed-effects models with gaussian errors. For an alternative framework, see this question: [How to choose nlme or lme4 R library for mixed effects models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/5344/930) Your formula reads as follows: your model includes a between- by within-subject interaction assuming [compound symmetry](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/15102/930) for the variance-covariance structure; subjects are considered random effects (in other words, this is a varying intercept model, as symbolized by the `~1|ID` formula for the `random` term). The `type="marginal"` argument indicates that you want to compute Type III sum of squares for fixed effects. (See [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11209/930) or [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/4544/930) question for issues with the different types of SSs, and discussion on the UCLA server on [How can I get Type III tests of fixed effects in R?](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/type3.htm)) This corresponds to what would be obtained using `aov()` with the appropriate error term (see the corresponding section in [Notes on the use of R for psychology experiments and questionnaires](http://www.psych.upenn.edu/~baron/rpsych/rpsych.html)). More details about R's formulas can be found on our [R's lmer cheat-sheet](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/13166/930).

For more information, you can refer to:

- John Fox's appendix on [Linear Mixed Models](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Fox-Companion/appendix-mixed-models.pdf) (2002).
- A nice guide to [R: Analysis of variance (ANOVA)](http://egret.psychol.cam.ac.uk/statistics/R/anova.html), full of illustrations for various experimental designs, which uses the [ez](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ez/index.html) package.
- Another tutorial on [Multilevel Linear Model](http://yatani.jp/HCIstats/MultilevelLinear)
- The [GLMM wiki](http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq), which summarizes the main issues raised on [r-sig-mixed-models](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/) mailing-list.

(And if you have some background in psychology, I'd recommend [*Practical Data Analysis for the Language Sciences with R*](http://magnuson.psy.uconn.edu/mirman/R/Baayen.pdf), by Baayen, which has a lot of illustrations on the analysis of crossed effects in psycholinguistic; there's also a R package, [languageR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/languageR/index.html).)

Finally, as you can see a lot has been discussed in related threads so it's worth browsing the [repeated-measures](/questions/tagged/repeated-measures) or [mixed-model](/questions/tagged/mixed-model) tags. I'd also like to put a direct link to a related thread that might be of interest: [Why do lme and aov return different results for repeated measures ANOVA in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/14088/930)

Answer (score -1):

For documentation, type `?lme` in your R console.

You also may want to try this:

```
anova_result <- aov(dv ~ between * within, data=dataframe)
TukeyHSD(anova_result)
```

(I admit I don't understand what all your arguments to `lme` are doing. You may be able to pass some of those same arguments to `aov`.)

Comment: Such a model doesn't account for the within-subject term because it assumes uncorrelated errors.