# Two-way ANOVA with Tukey post-hoc for unbalanced design with missing cell

Tags: anova, post-hoc, two-way

**My question:** when performing a two-way ANOVA (type III sum of squares), what is a valid approach to handling cells with zero observations?

**More details:**

I would like to apply a two-way ANOVA, followed by a Tukey post-hoc test, to statistically assess outputs from 2x4 factorial-design experiment. The experimental details are as follows:

```
Time point      Treatment  Number of observations
     0             Con               8
     0             Expo              0
     1             Con               8
     1             Expo              7
     2             Con               8
     2             Expo              8
     3             Con               8  
     3             Expo              8
```

Due to having unbalanced data and the expectation of interaction between factors, I believe it's appropriate for me to apply Type III sum of squares, such that unweighted marginal means are calculated. I am attempting to process this data in R using the 'Anova()' function, from the 'car' package.

Here is a minimum 'working' example:

```
#Data frame demonstrating study design
df = data.frame('Treatment' = c(rep('CON', 8), rep(c(rep('CON', 8),rep('EXPO', 8)), 3)), 
  'TimePoint' = c(rep('TP0', 8), rep('TP1', 16), rep('TP2', 16), rep('TP3', 16)))

#Generate mock dependent variable ('dv') values
set.seed(2)
df$dv = rep(rnorm(nrow(df)))

#install/load 'car' package
#install.packages('car')
library(car)

model = Anova(lm(testData[,ncol(testData)] ~ TimePoint * Treatment, 
             data=testData, 
             contrasts=list(TimePoint=contr.sum, Treatment=contr.sum)), type=3)
```

The above code generates an error:

```
Error in Anova.III.lm(mod, error, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
there are aliased coefficients in the model
```

I believe this relates specifically to the 0 observations at Time point 0, Treatment 'EXPO'.

The above data is from a typical toxicological study, in which time point 0 is the 'reference' group. As such, it was not justifiable to use an additional 8 organisms simply to balance the design and provide additional 'baseline' information.

Here are options I have considered:

1. Fill the empty Time point 0-Treatment 'Expo' (empty) cells with data duplicated from Time point 0-Treatment 'Con'. On the one-hand, this seems reasonable in that this the 'start' point from which the toxicological study was started, and the data from Time point 0-Treatment 'Con' is an entirely appropriate set against which to compare all other factor-level combinations.  At the same time, duplicating data for this purpose doesn't feel scientifically sensible/valid/defensible. I would very much appreciate CV member input on this.
2. Split the Time point 0-Treatment 'Con' data in half, assigning 50% to Time point 0-Treatment 'Con' and the other half to Time point 0-Treament 'Expo'. Again, I am not sure this is sensible, given that the way in which the data is split could affect the final statistical outputs.
3. I've considered the findings from another StackEx. post [Missing cells with Type III SS](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30900/missing-cells-with-type-iii-ss). This unfortunately only deals with an additive model, whereas I wish to use an interaction-based model.

I look forward to reading your suggestions.

MRJ.