# contrast for the interaction term

Tags: anova, interaction, contrasts

The link ([How to setup and interpret ANOVA contrasts with the car package in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12993/how-to-setup-and-interpret-anova-contrasts-with-the-car-package-in-r/350149#350149)) contains some code as you can see below, which gives an example of how to set up a contrast matrix based on a 2*2 factorial design. I have been trying to set up a contrast for the interaction term based on 2*3 design (two factors a and b, while a has 2 levels of a1 and a2, and b has 3 levels of b1, b2, and b3) without success. Could someone help me out?

```
> d$ab <- interaction(d$a, d$b)       # creates new factor coding the 2*2 conditions
> levels(d$ab)                        # this is the order of the 4 conditions
[1] "a1.b1" "a2.b1" "a1.b2" "a2.b2"

> aovRes <- aov(y ~ ab, data=d)       # oneway ANOVA using aov() with new factor

# specify the contrasts you want to test as a matrix (see above for order of cells)
> cntrMat <- rbind("contr 01"=c(1, -1,  0,  0),  # coefficients for testing a within b1
                   "contr 02"=c(0,  0,  1, -1),  # coefficients for testing a within b2
+                  "contr 03"=c(1, -1, -1,  1))  # coefficients for interaction
```

Thanks a lot!